# How to get an image's rgb matrix separately?

Tags: java

I have an image database and I want to store these image's RGB matrix in mysql db separately (Forexample : redMatrix_column, greenMatrix_column, blueMatrix_column ). In matlab I can get RBG matrix separately using imread() function. How to do this in java ? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you get the color components:

```
public class GetImageColorComponents {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(GetImageColorComponents.class
                                     .getResourceAsStream("/image.png"));
    int[] colors = new int[img.getWidth() * img.getHeight()];
    img.getRGB(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), colors, 0, img.getWidth());

    int[] red = new int[colors.length];
    int[] green = new int[colors.length];
    int[] blue = new int[colors.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      Color color = new Color(colors[i]);
      red[i] = color.getRed();
      green[i] = color.getGreen();
      blue[i] = color.getBlue();
    }
  }
}
```

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/5325399) for a complete example involving saving and retrieving the bytes in the MySQL database.

Comment: Thank you so much. I compared your red channel with matlab red channel both is same :) thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for your gist but When I used "byte" instead of "int", I am getting negative value in green[], red[], blue[] arrays. Is this a problem? Thanks again.

Comment: I think it is due to signed byte. Because if value >= 128 then it is being negative value.

Comment: You're right! Sorry, I missed that! Did you manage to fix it yourself?

Comment: Gist updated. To get the original value, one needs to use a multibyte integer type (short int or long), and and'ing the recorded bits with `0xFF` to get rid of the negative sign. Thanks for your report